# Sourcesafe 6.0 and vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010, sourcesafe-6.0

i used the source safe 6.0 with vb.net.Whenever i open the project,the project is getting to hanged and i take long time to write one word in the project. 
Is there any way to prevent Form hang while the code in the project using sourcesafe 6.0?
Is it even possible to integrate VS 2010 with VSS 6.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried SourceSafe 6.0 with VS 2008 and it works fine. It should work with VS 2010 as well using the MSSCCI plugin of VSS.

Does the same issue happens on other machines? If so, I recommend you upgrade to VSS 2005 and try again or switch to another source control tool.